# Can you recommend methods to keep track of time and timings in starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am a low level player who really wants to improve on the ladder. One of my biggest problems, and I guess for many low ladder players, is keeping track of the in-game time especially with respect to knowing when to get ready for potential attacks or windows for my own attacks.

For example: Players often say to expect Muta harass around 9 minutes.

Of course scouting information is a great way to get a fix on what to do when. If scouting is shut down though or, especially, in cases where I get harassed/make an early mistake and I feel under pressure I can lose any 'game-sense' in the match.

What do you recommend to try and keep track of time?

Comment: Can someone make a 'timing' tag or 'time-management' tag?

Comment: Get an eggtimer or stopwatch and put it next to your monitor?

Comment: I am concerned with the in-game time being different from 'real' time.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer, I wonder if you use this egg timer method. I have seen mention of egg-timers and the like on some forums. Is there any reason to use this over the in-game timer?

Comment: none at all. I wasn't aware there *was* an in-game timer before sth's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the options under "Gameplay" you can check "Show Game Timer" to get an in-game timer. It will be shown on the left side, above the mini map.

Comment: Well, that is sadly very simple. I really should check the options more thoroughly, thanks.

Comment: We're all guilty of that every once and awhile :P

Comment: This could use a nice screenshot to prove it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not only check timing... Timing is important, but **also is important to develop a "game feeling"!**

**For example**, if you play vs Zerg and 'usually' are expecting mutas around 9 minutes... you probably will build 1-2 cannons/turrets/spore crawlers (that is ok not only for low level players) in each of your mineral line (you should have main + natural till that time).

**BUT**, if in the early game you did good damage to your opponent he won't be able to get those mutas as usually. They will be 3-4 minutes later. So instead of investing 4-6 hundred minerals in those static defense right now ... you would better expand or build 1-2 ore production buildings. But don't forget about that defense 2 minutes later.

Another example: your opponent builds a bunch of infestors. For this case, I would say: don't care about mutas at all! If you see at least 1-2 infestors (or infestor pit), that usually means he will have 3-5 infestors more. In turn, that means either no mutas at all, or just a very small amount of them (at least in the nearest time) and you can deal easily with them with no static defense.

**The best way to know timing is to have game feeling**. To do that - you need to see an opponent army constantly. To do that in turn - harass constantly: don't waste your army for nothing, but keep opponent under pressure. So his mutas will go not to mineral line, but to your death ball...

Comment: Thanks Budda, This is really useful extra info. And is a problem I kn ow I have to work on. I doubt I am the only one that keeps my army too static.